# [ARCore][SceneForm] worldPosition after phone rotation

Tags: android, kotlin, coordinate-systems, arcore, sceneform

I am trying to create a node in front of the camera.

However, when I rotate the phone first (for example to 90° along the Y axis), and then create the node at the position (cameraPosition.x, cameraPosition.y, cameraPosition.z - distancetoNode), it creates the node in front of the old position of the camera, as if the phone did not rotate.

As I understand it, the coordinate system didn't move with the phone.
How can I make the node to be created in front the new position of the camera?

Thank you very much!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you rotate the camera the world position of the camera does not change but only its rotation.

In order to also account for the rotation you should use either the [camera pose](https://developers.google.com/ar/reference/java/com/google/ar/core/Camera) from the AR frame or use [Sceneform's camera](https://developers.google.com/ar/reference/java/com/google/ar/sceneform/Camera.html#screenPointToRay(float,%20float)) to create a ray from the center of your screen and position the node along that ray.